# How to pass a parameter in my method to return using a stateless session? minimize code duplication

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to pass a parameter in my method call, if set (its a boolean), then return a Stateless session.

I don't want to duplicate the QueryOver code, is there a way to have it like:

```
public virtual IList<User> GetAllUsers(bool isStateless)
{

  var query = QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.UserType == 1).ToList();

  if(isStateless)
    return NHibernateHelper.Session(query);
  else
    return NHibernateHelper.StatelessSession(query);

}
```

I know the above won't work, but I hope it is clear what I am after.

The only way I know is to basically duplicate the entire queryover code, and the only different between the code blocks will be that one will use .`Session` and the other will use .`StatelessSession`.

Hoping there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<User>().Where(x => x.UserType == 1);

IQueryOver<User, User> executableQuery;
if(isStateless)
    executableQuery = query.GetExecutableQueryOver(NHibernateHelper.Session);
else
    executableQuery = query.GetExecutableQueryOver(NHibernateHelper.StatelessSession);

return executableQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: I don't have that method GetExecutableQueryOver ?

Comment: have you really used `QueryOver.Of<User>()` instead of `Session.QueryOveryUser>()`?

Comment: Yes, you must use `NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver.Of<T>();`